# add data to asana via powershell

Tags: powershell, post, asana

Getting data from Asana seems to work fine, when I add data via `Invoke-RestMethod` it allows me to create a task but the name, notes field and assignee are not being populated.  Any ideas?

example:

```psh
function Add-asanaTask {
param([string]$apikey, [string]$taskName, [string]$notes, [string]$assignee, [string]$workspaceid,[string]$projectid, $url = 'https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces/{0}/tasks')
$apikey = "{0}:" -f $apikey
$url = $url -f $workspaceID
$url
$Mykey = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($apikey))
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization","Basic $Mykey")
$task =@{
    data=@{
        assignee= @{"id"=$assignee};
        name=$taskname;
        notes=$notes;
        projects=@{"id"=$projectid}
    }
}#end task object
$json = $task | ConvertTo-Json
$response = Invoke-RestMethod $url -Method Post -Body $json -Headers $headers 
return $Response.data
}

add-asanatask -apikey "apikey" -taskName "test task" -notes "hello world" -assignee "assignee ID"  -workspaceid "workspace ID" -projectid "project ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know powershell scripting syntax at all so I will not be of any help there.

However, I would be surprised if the `projects` parameter was working and the others were not as they are both in the same syntax.

I see that you have `assignee= @{"id"=$assignee}`.

Note that the syntax the API expects is `assignee=1235`. You can see an [example in curl on our documentation](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#create).